# How to populate a combobox list from the selection of another Combobox?

Tags: vb.net

I know there are many posting about this topic, but I'm not finding one that is helping me understand. I'm a VB newbie. I think I'm just not picking up on where everything goes in my code. 
So I am trying to select an item in a combobox and have that populate another combobox. Here is the code I tried.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If ComboBox1.Text = "AWS D17.1" Then
        ComboBox2.Items.AddRange("test", "Run")
    End If
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You

Comment: What errors do you get presently or what is not working as expected?

Comment: And it should be `ComboBox2.Items.AddRange({"test" , "run"})`

Comment: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Object()" and Too many arguments to "public Overloads Sub AddRange(items As Object()

Comment: Okay, that got rid of my errors, but it is not populating combobox2,

Comment: You sure you're looking at the right combobox?

Comment: That was it! I guess I needed that in the ComboBox1 section. Thank you again!

Comment: I am having another issue now, when I select an item from the first combobox it show in the second box, but when I select something else in the first box it doubled the selection in the second  box. and keeps adding to the list every time I change the box one selection. Do I need to add a Clear somehow to each selection?

Comment: This was meant to be on a separate thread. You should also check out the docs for a particular control you are currently learning how to use. Read up on the [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.8) control and you would know that a `Clear` method exists.

Comment: Okay, I will research ComboBox Clear. Thank you Again